# Best approach to save permanently an ArrayList of a personalised type

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I have an ArrayList of Persons `(ArrayList<Person>)`, I want to store that ArrayList in a persistent data type. SharedPreferences are a solution BUT it's just manipulating String, int, float`... variables. Do you have some ideas?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much simpler is to use java `Serialisation`.

You just need an Persons class:

```
public class Persons {

  ArrayList<Person> personList;
}
```

Then simply use

```
// init Persons
Persons person = new Persons();
// add some
persons.personList.add(new Person());

// write out
ObjectOutpuStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("personsDB.ser")));

oos.writeObject(persons);
oos.close();
```

read back with

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInpuStream(new FileInpuStream("personsDB.ser")));
persons = (Persons) ois.readObject();
ois.close();
// ready! Java does that all for you; since Persons is one object which contains something
```

The disadvantage is when battery power is lost during writing. Some people write to a temporary file first, delete the old and rename to the correct file name.

For high performance (much less space, much faster)
You could use `DataOutputStream`, but then you have to write all fields yourself (but this is simple too)

Comment: You write that to a file: if you dont delete it, then it is permanet

Comment: @androniennn updated: SQl Lite is a relation data base; You use this if you want to do queries: like give mee al persons with age > 18 and income < 30.000

Comment: and then when reading back, I have to make a loop to store persons variable in an ArrayList<person> ?

Comment: For kumaand answer, i mean the writing/reading into file part of his answer ;) (like yours)

Comment: If you can just edit your answer with the ArrayList part when reading back that will be perfect. I can already download json file from web and put it in a directory in sdcard.

Comment: ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInpuStream(new FileInpuStream("personsDB.ser"))); `ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInpuStream(new FileInpuStream("personsDB.ser")))`

Answer (score 2):

I'd store each `Person` in the array as a row in an SQLite database.  When you want to read it back into the program, each row becomes a `Person` object in the array.

Comment: Yep that's custom class. In fact, the ArrayList is retrieved from parsing a json file.

Comment: Edited my answer, but it's basically the same.

Comment: I agree, but is there any other simple solution? I'll use that list just when there is no internet connection, otherwise, it'll parse json file directly from web.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use database or write json response in to file and read it from file

Comment: I think that one is the best/simplest answer. Do you have please some portion of code to read from json file and put stream in an ArrayList?